# Find the highest unknown number of peak points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I want to find the highest peak points in the below histogram. For example as it is seen in the figure, I should select 4 peak points, but I get this 4 points information after seeing the histogram, so I need to find it by coding. Is there any method or algorithm to solve this problem?

[image]

If I select manually I could solve the problem. However, I do not know the number of the highest peak points. Actually the main problem is determining a threshold.

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(difference)
[sortedX,sortingIndices] = sort(difference,'descend');
locsize=size(locs,2);
counter=1;
peak_order=[];
while counter<5
    for j=1:locsize
        if sortingIndices(counter)==locs(j)            
            peak_order(counter)=sortingIndices(counter);
            counter=counter+1;
        end
    end
end

sorted_peak_order=sort(peak_order)enter code here
```

Comment: so simply add a threshold no ?

Comment: sort your array by decreasing size, then take the first 4 elements ...

Comment: But the problem is I do not know the "4" or any threshold value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findpeaks has [a series of options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#namevaluepairs) to refine your results. In your case, the option 'MinPeakProminence' should work; it thresholds according to the prominence of a peak to its neighbors.

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(difference,'MinPeakProminence',0.25*max(difference))
```